# Project Euler (#17)

Tags: c++

Problem 17 on project euler states:

If the numbers 1 to 5 are written out in words: one, two, three, four, five, then there are 3 + 3 + 5 + 4 + 4 = 19 letters used in total.
If all the numbers from 1 to 1000 (one thousand) inclusive were written out in words, how many letters would be used?
NOTE: Do not count spaces or hyphens. For example, 342 (three hundred and forty-two) contains 23 letters and 115 (one hundred and fifteen) contains 20 letters. The use of "and" when writing out numbers is in compliance with British usage.

I have looked over my code many times and cant find why it isn't solving it correctly, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

```
`#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

unsigned int value = 11;//one thousand = 11

short small(short x);
void two(short third);

int main()
{
    for(short count = 0;count<10;count++)
    {
        two(count);
    }
   std::cout<<value;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void two(short third)
{

    std::string temp;
    if(third>0)
    {
         third = (small(third) + 10);//10 = and(3) + hundred(7)
    }
    for(short i = 0;i<20;i++)//0-20
    {   
        value += (small(i) + third);      
    }
    for(short i = 20;i<60;i++)//20-40 + 80-100
    {
         std::stringstream ss;
         ss<<i;
         temp = ss.str();
         value += ((small(temp[1]-'0') + 6) + third);
    }
    for(short i = 40;i<70;i++)//40-70
    {
         std::stringstream ss;
         ss<<i;
         temp = ss.str();
         value += ((small(temp[1]-'0') + 5) + third);
    }
    for(short i = 70;i<80;i++)//70-80
    {
         std::stringstream ss;
         ss<<i;
         temp = ss.str();
         value += ((small(temp[1]-'0') + 7) + third);
    }      
}

short small(short x)
{
              switch(x)
             {
                case 0:
                     return 0;
                case 1:
                     return 3;
                case 2:  
                     return 3;
                case 3:
                     return 5;
                case 4:
                     return 4;
                case 5:
                     return 4;
                case 6:
                     return 3;
                case 7:
                     return 5;
                case 8:
                     return 5;
                case 9:
                     return 4;
                case 10:
                     return 3;
                case 11:
                     return 6;
                case 12:
                     return 6;
                case 13:
                     return 8;
                case 14:
                     return 8;
                case 15:
                     return 7;
                case 16:
                     return 7;
                case 17:
                     return 9;
                case 18:
                     return 8;
                case 19:
                     return 8;                   
          }
}
```

Comment: Had a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620571/project-euler-problem-17-python) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4245811/project-euler-problem-17-whats-wrong)? One mentions the 'eighteen'-issue which might have hit you, too?

Comment: Your function: `short small(short x)` does not return a value if called with a number larger than 19, you should really add a default return value, not that that is your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I had already seen those, in my code eighteen does = 8

Comment: just a quick observation - when you call two(x) - you are adding x into your total (if third>0 third += ....) - and I don't think you want to so that.

Comment: It returns the sum of the number of letters in all the numbers 1 to 1000, count represents the hundreds place so by I want to add it in my total

Comment: @Vesmir I got that much, what value does your function return? that is the actual number.

Comment: if you call two(1), then after third += (small(third) + 10); third will equal 14. is that what you want ?

Comment: Oh, your right, changing it now. it still doesnt find the correct value though

Comment: also, do you mean to double count the range 40-60 - it's included in two of your loops. Also, where to you add in "one hundred", "two hundred" etc.

Comment: and also, where do you add in numbers n80->n99?

Comment: @Jimmy the comments in the code should tell you that

Comment: ok, i still can't see where you're adding in 100,200,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to consider John Mashall's answer. The solution using strings is not optimal, you might consider extract the second digit using modulus 10 instead.

You aren't adding the round hundreds 100, 200, 300, 400, ... you add 101, 102, ... correctly but not the round hundreds. Inside your code that add the initial *and hundred* (10 characters) you should also add the length of *hundred* (7) (and one, two, thee, ...) to the value:

```
if(third>0)
{
     third = (small(third) + 10);//10 = and(3) + hundred(7)
     value += third - 3; // no need for the "and"
}
```

If I apply John Marshalls fix (using modulus instead) and apply the above I get the correct result of (hover mouse over box below to see result):

> 21124

Comment: Thanks, the modulus tip will be especially useful for future problems

Answer (score 1):

Your first error is that

```
ss.str() = "";
```

doesn't mean what you think it does.  You should print out `temp` in each of your loops to check that you're adding what you think you're adding to `value`.

Then you should simplify the problem: check that your program is producing and adding to `value` the right amounts for 1 to 10, 1 to 20, 1 to 100, 1 to 110, etc.  You'll find that it would be easier to debug your program if it was organised so that you could ask for the sum for any 1 to *n* -- for an *n* given on the command line, for example.